# Где в monodevelop сохраняется месторасположение директории решений?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, linux

Выбираем в меню

```
Файл->Новый->Проект...
```

Открывается окно "новое решение", там есть поле для выбора пути, названное "Расположение:". По умолчанию предлагается сохранять файлы в директорию `~/ == /home/user/`

Но это не очень удобно для процесса разработки в целом (потому что в моём дистрибутиве исходные тексты разных проектов по умолчанию размещаются в другой директории).

Как из консоли поменять этот путь по умолчанию (т.е. какой файл пропатчить при установке monodevelop)?